# Chart Library for native xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Which open source Chart Library is best for Native Xamarin ios and android?. I didn't find out anything in xamarin component store.

Comment: It is difficult to say which is the best. Please refer to [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14171/charts-in-xamarin) which can give us some suggestions about charts in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

The component store is deprecated. Take a look at Microcharts, ShinobiControls, OxyPlot. Google search with Xamarin + charts will also recommend some more options to look at.